# Optimize sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose there three columns `ename , city , salary`. There are millions of rows in this table named `emp`.

```
    ename  city    salary 
    ak    newyork  $5000
    bk    abcd     $4000
    ck    Delhi    $4000
    ....................
    ...................
   Maverick  newyork  $8000
```

I want to retrieve all employees having the same `city` name  as `Maverick`.

```
select * from emp where 
city = (select city from emp where ename= 'maverick' )
```

I know it will work, but for performance reasons, this query is not good because there are two `where` clauses present in this query.

I need a query having better performance than above query.

Comment: You generally cannot say if a query is efficient unless you have looked at the query plan.

Comment: Although there is certainly another way to write this query, I don't see what's wrong with this way.  Having two where clauses doesn't necessarily mean that performance will be poor.  Check the query plan, before you try to remove a problem that doesn't exist.  If it's performing poorly, it's probably due to a missing index; and rewriting the SQL won't help.

Comment: Incidentally, the simplest way of writing this is `select e1.* from emp e1 join emp e2 on e1.city = e2.city where e2.ename = 'Maverick'` - But I'm not posting that as an answer, because it won't be "a query having better performance", which is what you asked for.

Comment: @Maverick can you run select * from all_ind_columns where table_name = 'EMP' and give us the output, so that we can see what is currently indexed

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the same output but I doubt it will perform any better.

You could compare the plans though.

```
select x.*
  from emp x
  join (select city from emp where ename = 'maverick') y
    on x.city = y.city
```

You can also add 2 indexes, one on the ENAME column, and a separate one on the CITY column.

```
create index emp_idx_ename on emp(ename);
create index emp_idx_city on emp(city);
```

The first index will speed up the inline view whose results are being joined to, because it is searching the table on employee.

The second index will speed up the parent query, because it is searching the table for a given city.

You could create a composite index on emp(city, ename) as others have suggested since you're select only the city column where the ename is X, allowing the query in the inline view to use only the index and not the table, which I didn't initially think of. It may provide an additional boost, more or less, depending on the size of the table, although the index will also be larger.

To make sure the indexes will immediately use updated statistics related to that table, I would also run the following after you create the above indexes, so that your query will immediately start using them:

```
analyze table emp compute statistics;
```

Comment: Okay , it 'll execute and check the execution time for both query , Thank you for reply , your answer look more suitable

Answer (score 1):

Oracle is probably going to do a good job getting the optimal execution plan for this query:

```
select *
from emp 
where city = (select city from emp where ename= 'maverick' ) ;
```

What would help the query are two indexes:

```
create index idx_emp_ename_city on emp(ename, city)
create index idx_emp_ename_city on emp(city)
```

The first would be used for the subquery.  The second to look up all the matching rows.  Without indexes, Oracle is going to have to read the table at least once (I think at least twice) and that is going to affect performance on such a large table.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes complexity wins from the desire to narrow down the query further. Just isn't possible to optimize this query further.

You could opt to add an index to create better performance. The index should come on `city` and `ename`.

Try this to create these indexes:

```
create index emp_city -- for the outer where clause
on emp
( city
)

create index emp_ename_city -- for the sub query
on emp
( ename
, city
)
```

Comment: Yes , we can do . we can create index for both columns city and ename for fast retrieval of records . But.... is there another way to write the SQL query for same output .

Comment: There is, but they won't perform any better.

Comment: @Maverick: Did the use of the index help? I am sure the query itself isn't the problem.

Comment: it was the interview question , during the interview i answered we can create index for both columns which is used in where clause statement . But they ask ...is there any other SQL query which can have same output with better performance . By the way Thank you for your reply

Comment: A join won't help the performance in any way. The index is the solution.

Comment: Okay , So best i can do in this scenario....is to create index for both columns city and ename .

Comment: Two indexes as Gordon proposed would be best.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't see why you would create a composite index. That subquery has one condition in the where clause, and it's on ENAME. It does not filter in on any particular cities, just ENAME. The fact that CITY is in the SELECT list does not mean it should also be a part of the index. The only implication is that the index will be larger than it needs to be (since you put ENAME first at least), but the 2nd column of the index isn't needed as far as I can tell and would have no benefit to the query he's running

Comment: @BrianDeMilia: To prevent the need to use the table to get the `ename`. By adding it to the index there is no need to access the table. Thus in large tables this is a huge performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `with` statement... Users sugest you many dicisions

```
WITH new_city_tab AS (
  SELECT city AS ncity
  FROM   emp WHERE ename='Maverick'
  GROUP BY city)
SELECT *
FROM   emp e,
       new_city_tab c
WHERE  E.city = c.ncity;
```